# Not able to connect to azure database using pyodbc library

Tags: python-3.x, pyodbc

I am not able to connect to my azure database in python using pyodbc library.

When I pass the connection string in the below format:

*

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(
    'DRIVER={SQL Server};'
    'SERVER= servername;'
    'DATABASE=dbname;'
    'username=username;'
    'password=password'
)
```

- 

I get the following error:

**line 4, in 
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(
pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied.**

When I pass the connection string in the below format:

*

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(
    driver = '{SQL Server}',
    server = 'servername',
    database = 'dbname',
    username = 'username',
    password = 'password'
)
```

- 

I get the following error:

**line 4, in 
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(
pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('28000', "[28000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Login failed for user**

Answer (score 0):

In order to give you full answer please add where are trying to connect to the server from: your computer? a server?

Did you make sure that you IP is whitelisted ?

did you tied to connect to the DB with SSMS(sql server management studio) so you know for sure it is not a user/password issue?

A possible solution if you are trying from your windows base computer is to
to install ODBC Driver 13&17 and then change your code:

```
 driver = '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'
```

Comment: thanks for the answer.
The db is working on SSMS with the used user & password.

Comment: however, I installed ODBC Driver 17 and specified it in Driver, now it is giving the error as below:



`cnxn = pyodbc.connect(
pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('28000', "[28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user ''. (18456) (SQLDriverConnect); [28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Invalid connection string attribute (0); [28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user ''. (18456); [28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Invalid connection string attribute (0)")`

Comment: Did you install odbc driver 13 as well?

Comment: Also try to add  Trusted_Connection='Yes'

Comment: 13 is not getting installed as 17 ODBC driver is there
and 
I tried with trusted_connected = 'Yes' and 'No' both, is giving me login failed error.

Comment: I found the error in my code.
In the connection string, I just have to use UID/PWD nstead of Username & Password.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the correct format of the connection string:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(
    'DRIVER={SQL Server};'
    'SERVER= servername;'
    'DATABASE=dbname;'
    'UID=username;'
    'PWD=password'
)
```